# Another RegEx question

Tags: regex

I absolutely hate RegEx, I really need to learn it - it's so powerful. Here's the issue:

I'm trying to rewrite URLs in IIS, and I've got this default RegEx:

```
^([^/]+)/?$
```

However, that does let things like this `business/profile.html` through, but it lets `business-profile.html` through.

How do I change it so that it lets the former through?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? That will lead to a better answer.

Comment: I'm trying to add user-friendly URLs to my website, by use of URL rewriting in IIS 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to understand and learn Regex, learn to break down their meaning when you're confused as to what they're doing.  Here's the same regex, in expanded format.

```
^          # Start of the string
(          # Take a group...
    [^/]+  # of one or more characters (the +) that are NOT the / character
)          # end of the group
/?         # an optional '/'
$          # End of string
```

So this regex matches:

- All strings that don't have the `/` character in it
- All strings that contain a single `/` at the end of it

To "fix" the regex, we need to know what you really mean by "let through".  Do you mean "match the regex?"

(Side note: A great resource is http://www.regular-expressions.info/ - it provides a great cross-tool reference and tutorial for regex use.)

Comment: By let through, I mean, match the RegEx

Comment: +1, Although since we are not capturing anything, a non capturing group would be better, perhaps we can squeeze out some pre optimization from the engine also.

Comment: @ct2k7: Ok, then *what* are you trying to match?  How do you intend to rewrite the URLs?  What should turn into what else?  What's the input, and what's your desired output?

Comment: hi Robert, the input is: www.site.com/opd/cache.html, and on the server, this is: www.site.com/index.php?do=opd/cache.html Rewriting is done using IIS' function mechanism plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The original RE's purpose seems to be "forbid any URL with slashes inside" (one *at the end* is optionally allowed).  If your purpose is "forbid absolutely nothing", `^(.*?)/?$` should work (with the `*?` meaning non-greedy match -- RE dialects differ about such advanced things, so I don't know if yours will support it).  @Wrikken has shown how to allow "at most one slash inside", and that clearly generalizes to "at most N slashes inside" for any fixed N.  Without knowing exactly what you want to allow, and what to forbid, it's hard to be more helpful!-)